# EmberJS: controller not set for an appended view. Why?

Tags: ember.js

I am struggling with a bug in my Ember app. I was hoping someone could shed some light on what might be happening. 
One of my controllers' action adds a view:

```
addView: function(){
    var view = Ember.View.create({
        templateName: 'to_be_added',
        controller: this
    });
    view.append();
}
```

My template looks like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="to_be_added">
    Added view.
    {{controller}}
</script>
```

I know it is supposed to work (and it does in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XWzWp/1/). But in the context of my app, it fails. The controller is not setup for the view: `{{controller}}` is `null`.

I can't figure out what is happening. Any ideas?

Thanks,
PJ

Comment: The fiddle works for me.

Comment: I know, for me too. But the "same" scenario in the context of my app (which has a lot more nested routes, controllers etc), it fails. Hence it is really hard to track down. I was hoping someone stumbled upon the same issue in a bigger app?

Comment: Ah, i didn't read this part in your part properly. From this snippet, no one will be able to give you a hint. From the code i am seeing here, this is an unpossible behaviour. You are using the same Ember Version in the fiddle and your app? And it seems a little awkward to me that you are messing around with views in your controller. Are you really using view.append or are you using the render method in one of your routes?

Comment: Yes, I am using the same: Ember RC1, Handlebars RC3. I am new to Ember so maybe I am doing things wrong: I am indeed using view.append() in a controller. I guess that could be why I am seeing this strange behaviour. Weird though that it works fine in the stripped down JSFiddle...